# Careers 2.0 profile fails to update city

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I am reporting one of the weird bugs I have encountered today when I created my profile by accepting the invitation.

When I accepted the invite, it asked for my city, state, zip, with everything in one field separated by commas. By mistake I entered my area name "Thaltej" before my city which is "Ahmedabad".

So I wrote like this: "Thaltej, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India 380054" or something like that.

After few clicks in the Profile form I saw that it was indicating "Thaltej, India" instead of either "Gujarat, India" which is "State, Country" or "Ahmedabad, India" which is "City, Country". Now, to correct my mistake I clicked on "edit" link to edit, and after the correction I saved the changes, but that made no difference. I went back and clicked on "edit" again but in the City field was still "Thaltej" instead of "Ahmedabad". I corrected it quite a few times but the City field would not store the updated value for City.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. I tried logging out and logging in but there was no difference.

Comment: Bug I have reported is completed different than what possible duplicate has mentioned. In my case what happens is "City" field is free-text as of now and even if I change it from "A" to "B" it does not save at all. If I change it from "A" to "B", it tries to save and when it gets back in view mode it still shows up "A" only even if you refresh your webpage.

@jonsca I hope I am able to explain how it is different than possible duplicate match.

Comment: I am having what I believe to be this exact same problem with my profile, except the city field is blank.  Adding a city name to the field and clicking Save does not save the city name- after a page refresh, the city name remains blank.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well.

Comment: Any update on this bug?  It seems this would be a fairly simple fix.

Comment: Wow is anyone going to fix this bug?

Comment: haven't heard anything on it yet.

Comment: I apologize for the time it's taken to answer this.  We're running through some housecleaning now and processing the bug list for careers now has a dedicated person each week.

Answer (score 1):

If you get rid of the postal code, it will correctly select the name "Ahmedabad, India".

Our system always tries to select the most precise location it can and the names for the locations are stored on the geo coordinates for the location.  Since it can select something more specific than Ahmedabad, it gladly chooses to and displays the name of the more specific locale.  This is something you might like if you just enter the State and Zip, it will choose the most specific level it can, zip, and use whatever name is attached to it.  So for instance if you enter only 10006 as the zip code and no other fields except the country, it will still display New York, NY as the City/State combo.

If you want to select the name of the nearest major region, you'll have to make sure you only enter enough information so that region is the most specific location selectable.